# Validating PKCS#7 detached signature on Android using BouncyCastle [NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11]

Tags: android, bouncycastle, pkcs#7, spongycastle

Currently trying to validate a PKCS#7 signature, where the verified content is the SHA-256 hash of a file and receiving the below error.

Error

```
org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: can't create digest calculator: exception on setup: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 for provider BC
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.doVerify(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.verify(Unknown Source)
```

Code

```
    private fun verifySignature(sha256Hash: ByteArray, base64Signature: String): Boolean {
        val signedData = CMSSignedData(
            CMSProcessableByteArray(sha256Hash),
            Base64.decode(base64Signature, Base64.DEFAULT).inputStream()
        )
        val store: Store<X509CertificateHolder> = signedData.certificates
        signedData.signerInfos.signers.forEach { signer ->
            try {
                val certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.sid as Selector<X509CertificateHolder>)
                val certHolder = certCollection.first()
                val cert =
                    JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder)
                if (signer.verify(
                        JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert)
                    )
                ) {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Additional Info:

```
'compileSdk'      : 30
'buildTools'      : '30.0.2'
'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:1.72'
'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.72'
'org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk18on:1.72'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following resolved my issues

```
    private val BC = BouncyCastleProvider().apply {
        addAlgorithm("Alg.Alias.MessageDigest.1.2.840.113549.1.1.11", "SHA-256")
    }.also { Security.insertProviderAt(it, 1) }
```

Comment: may you provide more details? where did you add this line on code and how did yyou use it?

Comment: This should be set as a global value within a singleton class